# Do I have to tell Apache Batik rasterizer where to find fonts (and if so, how)?

Tags: linux, fonts, highcharts, batik

I have been using Highcharts on a Windows-based webserver and have recently migrated to a Oracle Enterprise Linux server instead.  I'm having an issue with fonts when I export charts to PNG format: the fonts in the SVG are not being honoured.

I have followed instructions  in various places to [install Microsoft fonts](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-do-i-install-and-use-fonts-in-linux/238/) and to ensure that Lucida Grande (the preferred font family, as specified in the SVG) is [installed as a TrueType font](http://fahdmirza.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/steps-to-install-profilerpictogramtff.html) on the Linux machine.

Despite my efforts (including using `-font-family` option of the rasterizer to specify a default font family), all the fonts in generated PNGs come out as something bold and italic (I don't know what font it is).

So, in summary, my questions are:

1. Should Batik rasterizer automatically be able to use whatever fonts are installed on the Linux machine?
2. Do I have to tell the rasterizer where the fonts are?
3. Have I installed fonts correctly, judging from the links I supplied above?  (Both appeared successful.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it!

The answers to my questions are:

1. Yes.
2. No.
3. Yes.

The issue was that when I followed the [instructions to install TrueType fonts](http://fahdmirza.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/steps-to-install-profilerpictogramtff.html), this was done as `root` but the permissions weren't automatically set, meaning that other users (like the `apache` user that runs the webserver) weren't allowed to read the font files.

The fix, therefore, was:

```
cd /usr/share/fonts
chmod 755 ttfonts/
cd ttfonts/
chmod 644 *.*
```